# Cannot download Docker image from repository

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerhub

I am trying to create a swarm setup on my laptop. I am running swarm daemon on laptop, and running 2 Ubuntu 14.04 VM as docker node. On one of the nodes I am able to run swarm and I can connect to swarm daemon. I can list the node with docker info and spawn a container on it. But when I try to pull swarm image on another VM node, I get the following error:

```
pensu@pensu-virtual-machine:~$ sudo docker pull swarm
Pulling repository swarm
FATA[0025] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/swarm/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout
```

I checked and someone said it's a proxy issue. But I am not using any proxy server. Here are other relevant information:

```
pensu@pensu-virtual-machine:~$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Here is my /etc/default/docker:

```
pensu@pensu-virtual-machine:~$ cat /etc/default/docker 
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

**Update:
This is something different. I was trying this all from home. Today morning I came to office, logged in and voila, I was able to pull the image!**

**Not sure what is the reason, but looks like I will need to come to office to pull docker images!**

Comment: I'm using boot2docker and I could solve "timeout" issue by simply restarting boot2docker like described here https://forums.docker.com/t/pulling-docker-images-i-o-timeout/740/4

Comment: I am also facing this issue, any solution, anyone?

Answer (score 17):

Just stop and restart your docker host:

```
boot2docker stop
boot2docker start
```

Credits to: https://forums.docker.com/t/pulling-docker-images-i-o-timeout/740/6

Answer (score 8):

Updated for modern times:

```
docker-machine stop default
docker-machine start default
```

(`docker-machine restart default` doesn't fix it).

Comment: restart fixes it for me in mid 2016

Answer (score 3):

This error message:

- lookup index.docker.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout

tells that connection to local dns server (127.0.1.1:53) ends with timeout.

I guess this issue is connected with network/dns configuration on virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my solution for this is, run following commands.

```
boot2docker stop 
boot2docker delete
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

This basically delete the vm image use by boot2docker and start over. This won't delete your local images.Then execute docker pull command.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions that are stated but they didn't help. What fixed the problem for me is the tip posted [here](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/718),

```
docker-machine sssh
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
exit
```

Comment: When docker-machine is started it writes the router's resolved nameserver to `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you then switch networks (between home and the office say) without restarting docker-machine it uses the resolved name server from the network DM was started on. 

This solution is quicker than a start/stop. Next step us to reconfiguring my home networks to use public nameservers.

command above should read `docker-machine ssh`

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, it turned out the image had already been downloaded before, but it was defect due to a problem during the earlier download.

I'm not sure why this lead to the above error message, but after removing the image, it downloaded without problems.

So to fix it:

```
docker image ls
```

Note the id of the problem image, then

```
docker image rm <id>
```

Then re-download

```
docker pull <image-name>
```