# Running a docker container run Ubuntu result in daemon error

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run an ubuntu image as a docker container:

```
docker container run -it --name myubuntu ubuntu
```

But i'm getting an error of:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup
>   registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp
>   10.0.2.15:55341->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout.

Here is my `docker container version`:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      19.03.3
  API version:  1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.12.10
  Git commit:   a872fc2f86
  Built:        Tue Oct  8 01:01:20 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
 containerd:
  Version:      v1.2.10
  GitCommit:            b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:      1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:            3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:      0.18.0
  GitCommit:            fec3683
```

Comment: Do you run behind proxy server?

Comment: Probably not, for intance run nginx works fine

Comment: Try ping docker.io from your engine machine

Comment: The error message suggests a connectivity problem with your local DNS service.  This isn't really a programming question _per se_, and the solutions tend to be rather installation-specific.  The answers to [Cannot download Docker image from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884488/cannot-download-docker-image-from-repository) boil down to "restart the Docker VM", for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`docker-machine restart`

AND / OR

`docker-machine regenerate-certs`